# Terraform. The true and false result expressions must have consistent types

Tags: terraform, devops

I am using one Terraform file for AWS and Azure. It depends on the value of variable, I deploy to AWS or Azure. For the solution, I use "count".

But in one of the places I have an issue.

For AWS in for_each construction necessary use [], but for azure I have to use {}.

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "selected_es" {
  count = local.current_provider == "aws" ? 1 : 0
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.selected_es[0].id
}

data "aws_subnet" "selected_es" {

  for_each = local.current_provider == "aws" ? data.aws_subnet_ids.selected_es[0].ids : []
  id       = each.value
}
```

I understand, that in variant with AWS I have an array with IP's. With Azure, I have another type. But I don't understand, how I can solve my problem.

Some describe. At now works only if I use separate part of code for Azure and AWS:
1 variant. local.current_provider = aws.
Our "data.aws_subnet_ids.selected_es[0].ids" is array. 
In my foreach I have to use

```
for_each = local.current_provider == "aws" ? data.aws_subnet_ids.selected_es[0].ids : []
```

2 variant. local.current_provider = azure. 
Our "data.aws_subnet_ids.selected_es[0].ids" isn't array (because count in datasource will be 0).
In my foreach I have to use

```
for_each = local.current_provider == "aws" ? data.aws_subnet_ids.selected_es[0].ids : {}
```

But I want to use one code for 2 variants.
I can't use

```
data "aws_subnet" "selected_es" { 
  count local.current_provider == "aws" ?1:0 
  for_each = data.aws_subnet_ids.selected_es[0].ids 
  id = each.value 
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify how azure fits into this code? All your code uses aws resources. Also writing "have another type" is not specific. What type exactly it is?

Comment: I use azure in other files. My example from aws_elasticsearch managed solution. I don't need to deploy in Azure. But I want to have one repo for the deployment of my infrastructure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your issue. Msg error is clear. You an't have `local.current_provider == "aws"?[]:{}`. It must be `local.current_provider == "aws"? []:[]` or `local.current_provider == "aws"?{}:{}`.

Comment: Please don't add code to comments, but edit question with properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: Ok. Update my question post.

Comment: Sadly you can't do this. You can't mixed return types in your comparison expression. Its better to seperate to code, rather then to look for things that TF does not support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I created a difficult infrastructure in Azure and AWS using one code. It's one place, where I have a problem. ((((
Try to think, how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you solve this is by converting the values to String so Terraform plays along like so :

```
jsondecode(local.current_provider == "aws" ? jsonencode([]) : jsonencode({}))
```